# Swift getters implicitly returning expressions

Tags: swift

The docs for Swift say

```
Shorthand Getter Declaration
If the entire body of a getter is a single expression, the getter implicitly returns that expression.
```

But for this Temperature converter an error arises: Missing return in a function expected to return 'Float'

```
class Temperature {
    var celsius: Float = 0.0
    var fahrenheit: Float {
        get {
            ((celsius * 1.8) + 32.0)
        }
        set {
            celsius = (newValue - 32)/1.8
        }
    }
}
```

How can I declare this class with the getter implicitly returning an expression?

Comment: Use Swift 5.1 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression:

```
    get {
        ((celsius * 1.8) + 32.0)
    }
```

won’t compile unless you are using Xcode 11 / Swift 5.1. If you want your code to compile in an earlier version, say `return` explicitly.

```
    get {
        return ((celsius * 1.8) + 32.0)
    }
```